# main_menu variable is always empty in drupal theme Zen

Tags: css, menu, drupal-7, drupal-theming, zen

I am new to `drupal theming` and trying to edit the `menu` for a `sub theme` with base theme as `Zen`. But when I tried to add `class` and `div` to the `main menu`, I saw its not changing. Later when I `print_r($main_menu)` in `page.tpl.php` in my subtheme directory, it is showing empty results ! But the same `print_r($main_menu)` shows the main menu array in `Bartik` theme's `page.tpl.php` ! How can I create the main_menu variable in my theme ?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this would solve your problem

https://drupal.org/project/menu_attributes

Regards,
Immanuel Paul